# Importing cv in PyDev Console

Tags: python, eclipse, opencv, pydev

I have 64 bit python, numpy, and other packages including opencv.

I don't have any problem with following statement in MSDOS console by running python.exe

```
  import cv
```

But when I did the same thing in PyDev console in Eclipse, I got following error.

```
 import cv
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cv.py", line 1, in <module>
     from cv2.cv import *
 ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some period of trial & error, I found deleting and creating new python interpreter of PyDev solved the problem. More specifically,

1. Go to Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Python Interpreters
2. Select current interpreter and click Remove button
3. Click Auto Config button and select necessary folders for PYTHONPATH
4. Click Apply